# Javascript: Error about opening a folder and renaming the files every x secs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am very new in JS and Nodejs and i am trying to
make a script that: every 1 sec it will read the files of the folder and after doing a specific task with the rows of every file will rename the files. The code bellow is my implementation:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");


const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
console.log(directoryPath);

function FTP(){

        console.log("------------- SCAN THE DIRECTORY --------------------------")
        fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
            
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
            } 

                files.forEach(function (file) {    
                    console.log(`${file}`)
                        
                            fs.createReadStream(`${directoryPath}/${file}`)
                            .pipe(parse({ delimiter: `\t`, from_line: 2 }))
                            .on("data", function (row) {

                                let arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, row));  // convert array to string
                                let stringToJsonObject_row = JSON.parse(arrayToString); 
                                // DO A JOB ....
                            })
                            .on("end", function () {
                                console.log("finished");
                            })
                            .on("error", function (error) {
                                console.log(error.message);
                            })
                        
            });

        })

        fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
            
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
            } 

            
            files.forEach(function (file) {    
                        
                fs.rename(`${directoryPath}/${file}`,`${directoryPath}/${file}0`,  () => {
                console.log(`${file} Has been renamed`)});
                        
            });

        });

}

setInterval(FTP, 1000);
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I GET:

```
/home/nikos/Desktop/TL2/FTP_server/Documents
------------- SCAN THE DIRECTORY --------------------------
sample_new
sample_new1
sample_new Has been renamed
sample_new1 Has been renamed
finished
finished
------------- SCAN THE DIRECTORY --------------------------
sample_new0
sample_new10
sample_new0 Has been renamed
sample_new10 Has been renamed
finished
finished
------------- SCAN THE DIRECTORY --------------------------
sample_new00
sample_new100
sample_new00 Has been renamed
sample_new100 Has been renamed
finished
finished
------------- SCAN THE DIRECTORY --------------------------
sample_new000
sample_new1000
sample_new000 Has been renamed
sample_new1000 Has been renamed
finished
finished
------------- SCAN THE DIRECTORY --------------------------
sample_new0000
sample_new10000
sample_new0000 Has been renamed
sample_new10000 Has been renamed
finished
finished
------------- SCAN THE DIRECTORY --------------------------
sample_new00000
sample_new100000
sample_new00000 Has been renamed
sample_new100000 Has been renamed
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/nikos/Desktop/TL2/FTP_server/Documents/sample_new00000'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/nikos/Desktop/TL2/FTP_server/Documents/sample_new00000'
}

[Done] exited with code=1 in 6.107 seconds
```

As it seems for a few iteration, it works but then i take the above error, can anyone explain me why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand after reading about asynchronous programming, i think that due to nodejs is non-blocking, it does not wait for the IO, it goes to the bellow lines of code and when the file is going to be processed, it is already renamed by the renaming commands. Do you think this is a correct explanation?